# Loop over Check or EditBox

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, checkbox, mfc

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and  have 10 check boxes on my form and created variables for each of them by naming m_CheckBox1,m_CheckBox2,m_CheckBox3 .... m_CheckBox10 and also for edit boxes(m_EditBox1 ... so on).

I want to check if the check boxes are checked in a loop and if the edit box value is not desired one, will show Message box error.If it the value is OK then move to next check box and edit box. How can I move to next checkbox simply like

```
    for (i=1;i < 11 ;i++)
         {
           is_checked = m_Checkboxi.GetCheck();
            if is_checked==1
              {do sth. with m_EditBox(i)}
            else
             do sth.
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Do not store a variable per checkbox. Instead, since the checkboxes logically form an array of choices, store them in an array as well. This would be a good time to depart from using wizards and understand the generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of those 10 variables and put in an array:

CButton m_CheckBox[10];

Also edit the resource.h file if necessary to make the 10 IDs consecutive. You will have to replace the DDX_Control calls in DoDataExchange to use the array in a loop:

```
CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CHECK1 + i, m_CheckBox[i]);
```

Comment: Or if you can't change the resource IDs, declare a static array of ints containing the resource IDs in order.

Comment: ScottMcP-MVP : if resource id is not contiguous then how it will work :(

Comment: The comment by john_e explains how it can work if the IDs are not contiguous.